# How to read the state of Num Lock using Cocoa / Quartz?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, quartz-graphics

I need to read the current state of *Num Lock* key without actually pressing it.
I've used the following (in Quartz) which succeeds in this, but does this for *Caps Lock* as i can't found the equivalent mask for *Num Lock*.

```
bool status = (CGEventSourceFlagsState(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState) 
               & kCGEventFlagMaskAlphaShift);
```

I've also used the mask `kCGEventFlagMaskNumericPad`, thinking it's the equivalent for num lock, but doesn't work as [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGEventFlags) also confirm.

Is there any way to read the state *asynchronously* in either Quartz / Cocoa ?

I'm using *Mountain Lion 10.8.4*.

Comment: NumLock doesn't seem to have a standard key code or exist as a documented modifier flag.  You might try manually observing the value of all present modifier values before and after activating it to see if the eventing subsystem even knows about it.

Comment: @CodaFi, thanx for the comment ;) I'll try this way

Comment: I don't think OS X has a real Num Lock state. On a full keyboard with a numeric keypad, there's no way to make those keys not produce numbers. You can't make them behave as arrows, Page Up, Home, etc. So, it's as though Num Lock were always on. On some laptop keyboards, there's a mode to turn part of the main keyboard into a numeric keypad, but that happens below the level visible to apps. It might be purely in the hardware. It just makes those keys produce key codes as though they were the keypad of a full keyboard.

Comment: FWIW, Apple keyboards with numeric keypads have no Num Lock key.

Comment: The `kCGKeyboardEventKeycode` equivalent for Numlock on OS X is `71` ... aka the `Clear` key.

Comment: Thanx all, it seems _num lock_ have no significance in Mac or doesn't appear at all ;) I was just trying to find equivalents to `GetKeyState` and `XGrabKey_x` of Windows / Linux. If there's no easy way or doesn't make sense to do that in OSX, then i'll leave it that way. It doesn't seem to be a _cross-platform_ thing anyway. @l'L'l, thanx, i'll give it a try ;)